# How to use a variable being created in a powershell script inside a yaml file in azure devops?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration

So I have a PowerShell script that generates a version number based on the current day and time and I want to use the result of this process inside a "NuGet Pack" task which takes in an environment variable as the version of the packed NuGet package how can I achieve this?
My YAML code:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  name: HrgWin
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'x86'
  buildConfiguration: 'ReleaseBeta'
  mainProj: 'PayRoll\PayRoll.csproj'
  publicProj: 'PublicPayRollDll\PublicPayRollDll.csproj'
  reportProj: 'PayRollDll\PayRollReportDll.csproj'
  nugConfig: $(NugetConfigPath)
stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
      - job: BuildJob
        steps:
          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                # Create an instance of the PersianCalendar
                 $persianCalendar = New-Object System.Globalization.PersianCalendar
                
                 # Get the current date and time in Gregorian calendar
                 $gregorianDate = Get-Date
                
                 # Convert the Gregorian date to Shamsi (Jalali) calendar
                 $shamsiYear = $persianCalendar.GetYear($gregorianDate)
                 $shamsiMonth = $persianCalendar.GetMonth($gregorianDate)
                 $shamsiDay = $persianCalendar.GetDayOfMonth($gregorianDate)
                
                 # Modify the Shamsi year to start with "99"
                 $modifiedShamsiYear = "99" + $shamsiYear.ToString().Substring(2)
                
                 $versionNumber = $modifiedShamsiYear + "." + $shamsiMonth + "." + $shamsiDay
                $patchedVersionNumber = $versionNumber + "." + $gregorianDate.ToString("HHmm")
                Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=payrollCurrentVersionNumber;isOutput=true]$patchedVersionNumber"
           - task: NuGetCommand@2
             inputs:
             command: 'pack'
             packagesToPack: '$(publicProj)'
             versioningScheme: 'byEnvVar'
             versionEnvVar: 'payrollCurrentVersionNumber'
```

As you can see I have tried using "##vso[task.setvariable variable=payrollCurrentVersionNumber;isOutput=true]$patchedVersionNumber" and yes I have tried putting the variables in these formats: $(payrollCurrentVersionNumber), payrollCurrentVersionNumber
I also have tired declaring an empty variable with the same name in the YAML file to see if it fills it but no.

Comment: Share the output of the `NuGetCommand@2` task, is there any error you get? What does the env variable show in the build output

Comment: The issue is that the **Write-Host** cmdlet in `PowerShell` is not actually setting the value of the `payrollCurrentVersionNumber` variable. It is just printing the value to the console.To set the variable to `payrollCurrentVersionNumber,` you can use the following command: `Set-Variable -Name payrollCurrentVersionNumber -Value $patchedVersionNumber`. Using this command, the value will be stored in `payrollCurrentVersionNumber`, and same you can use it in **NuGet**.

Comment: @Sibtain The exact error is: "##[error]No value was found for the provided environment variable"

Comment: Did you use the above command to set the variable? Is it working?"

Comment: @VenkatV Yes!! thank you very much it works perfectly, I created a local variable with the same name and added the command you provided (but the Write-Host command was also necessary for it to work) and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you can see I have tried using "##vso[task.setvariable
> variable=payrollCurrentVersionNumber;isOutput=true]$patchedVersionNumber" and yes I have tried putting the variables in these formats: $(payrollCurrentVersionNumber),payrollCurrentVersionNumber I also have tired declaring an empty variable with the same name in the YAML file to see if it fills it but no

The issue is that the **Write-Host** cmdlet in `PowerShell` is not actually setting the value of the `payrollCurrentVersionNumber` variable. It is just printing the value to the console. To set the variable to `payrollCurrentVersionNumber,` you can use the following command:

```
Set-Variable -Name payrollCurrentVersionNumber -Value $patchedVersionNumber
```

Using this command, the value will be stored in `payrollCurrentVersionNumber`, and same you can use it in **NuGet**

Here is the updated `Yaml` script.

```yaml
    stages:
      - stage: Build
        jobs:
          - job: BuildJob
            steps:
              - task: PowerShell@2
                inputs:
                  targetType: 'inline'
                  script: |
                    # Create an instance of the PersianCalendar
                    $persianCalendar = New-Object System.Globalization.PersianCalendar
    
                    # Get the current date and time in Gregorian calendar
                    $gregorianDate = Get-Date
    
                    # Convert the Gregorian date to Shamsi (Jalali) calendar
                    $shamsiYear = $persianCalendar.GetYear($gregorianDate)
                    $shamsiMonth = $persianCalendar.GetMonth($gregorianDate)
                    $shamsiDay = $persianCalendar.GetDayOfMonth($gregorianDate)
    
                    # Modify the Shamsi year to start with "99"
                    $modifiedShamsiYear = "99" + $shamsiYear.ToString().Substring(2)
    
                    $versionNumber = $modifiedShamsiYear + "." + $shamsiMonth + "." + $shamsiDay
                    $patchedVersionNumber = $versionNumber + "." + $gregorianDate.ToString("HHmm")
                    Set-Variable -Name payrollCurrentVersionNumber -Value $patchedVersionNumber
    
              - task: NuGetCommand@2
                inputs:
                  command: 'pack'
                  packagesToPack: '$(publicProj)'
                  versioningScheme: 'byEnvVar'
                  versionEnvVar: 'payrollCurrentVersionNumber'
```

You can use the `payrollCurrentVersionNumber variable` in the `NuGet Pack` task by setting the `versionEnvVar` parameter to `payrollCurrentVersionNumber`.

Comment: `Write-Host cmdlet in PowerShell is not actually setting the value of the payrollCurrentVersionNumber variable. It is just printing the value to the console`. This statement is wrong it is NOT "just printing the value to the console". This is how you [set variables in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#about-tasksetvariable) in Azure pipelines.

Answer (score -1):

Since you have set `payrollCurrentVersionNumber` as an output variable using `isOutput=true`, you need to refer the variable by including its task name.

> - Output variables set in the same job without the isoutput parameter.    To reference these variables, you'll use macro syntax.
>   Example:    $(myVar).
> - Output variables set in the same job with the isoutput    parameter. To reference these variables, you'll include the task
>   name. Example: $(myTask.myVar).

So you can use `$(myTask.myVar)` in the `NuGetCommand@2` task

Read more about the [Levels of output variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#levels-of-output-variables)